# How to create a factory with images for testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-factory

I need to create a factory that create images for testing. The factory should create images and save them on storage and after the test everything should be erased.

How can I do that ?

What I am thinking now is to put the *fields at null* on the factory and then using the `afterCreating` method to save the images manually but it has to be a better way to do that right ?

What I want to achieve is :

```
factory(Category::class)->create();
```

That will generate all images.

**$faker->image does not work anymore since LoremPixel (the provider) is really slow or down most of the time.**

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) major question here is why do you need to create actual images instead of using a [fake storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#storage-fake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleaner way I found is:

1. Set the value at null on the factory

   ```
   $factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
       return [
           'img' => null,
      ];});
   ```
2. Use $factory->afterCreating to override the value and save the
   image

   ```
   $factory->afterCreating(Category::class, function ($category, $faker) {
      $category->img = UploadedFile::fake()->image(uniqid() . '.jpg')->store('categories');
      $category->save();
   });
   ```
3. Create a fake storage on test setUp() and reset it on tearDown()

   protected function setUp(): void {parent::setUp();Storage::fake('public');}

   protected function tearDown(): void{
       Storage::fake('public');
   }

This solution creates images for testing and remove everything after it.

(Sorry for code sample, I can't make it indent properly)

Answer (score 3):

You can surely create images with faker for testing as below,

```php
<?php

use App\Category;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->word,
        'icon' => $faker->image('public/storage/test-images', 640, 480, null, false),
    ];
});
```

When you call `factory(\App\Category::class)->create();` it will create an image inside **test-images/** directory with specified dimensions.

Below is the signature of `image()`, which is self-explanatory,

```php
@method string image($dir = null, $width = 640, $height = 480, $category = null, $fullPath = true, $randomize = true, $word = null)
```

The only thing is you need to clear the `test-images` directory once the test run is completed.

Comment: $faker->image does not work anymore since LoremPixel (the provider) is really slow or down most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate fake images using  `$faker->image`.

Here is an example

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker; 
$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [

        'amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 10000),
        'image' => $faker->image('public/storage/images',640,480, null, false),

    ];
});
```

Comment: I think $faker->image does not work anymore since LoremPixel (the provider) is really slow or down most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, LoremPixel is down, but there are alternative packages available to use such as "mmo/faker-images" or "alirezasedghi/laravel-image-faker". I would suggest trying the latter package, which provides faker images from multiple sources like Lorem Picsum, LoremFlickr, PlaceDog, Kittens (Random Cats), and Fake People. You can find it at: https://github.com/alirezasedghi/laravel-image-faker.